# .htaccess rewrite all image.php to their respective image URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm wondering if there is a rule I can add to my .htaccess file that will make the URL of an image to appear as another image URL. Here is the use case I'm referring to:

My app automatically watermarks images using the GD library on the fly. In turn, the newly watermarked image has an image source of `localhost/some/dir/image.php?original=someFilename.png`.

Is it possible to make that dynamic image URL appear as the original, but still serve the dynamic, watermarked image? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (currently testing it):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.png)$ /some/dir/image.php?original=$1
```

Works for me, but you probably do not want to allow any characters in the filename (".+").
The following would be much more restrictive but also safer:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9]+\.png)$ /some/dir/image.php?original=$1
```